# Random words/text going bold in Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts

I'm having issues with how the fonts are rendering on a site I'm working on   the font-weight is all 300 and I'm using the Google font lato. This issue only seems to be on Google chrome i've tried it on different versions of chrome i.e. windows and Linux and different browsers i.e. Firefox and safari. I had the import code in my style sheet but have since removed it and put it in the html but to no avail. I've also got -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; on.

[I have uploaded an image to show you how the font is rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJ6W1.png)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: So what problem you actually referring to - bold font in some of the words? Can you post some code for that? Or maybe a link to it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for the welcome, yes this is the problem I'm referring to when the browser is refreshed the issue disappears and doesn't happen all the time. The font-weight is correct and there are no addition tags that would cause the font to go bold. i've found this link who seems to have the same problem  http://forums.htmlhelp.com/index.php?showtopic=43594 but doesn't seem to get an answer, thanks for this I will try and get some code to replicate the issue I'm having.

Comment: I have figured out what was causing the problem. I haven't been able to replicate it on a stack snippet, but i can give the example code I started to build which may give people some idea?

Comment: I am having the same problem using Lato, and it only happens in the Windows version of Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help with this. I managed to solve the problem, the issue was setting `font-feature-settings: "kern","liga","frac","pnum";` to the body of my pages this caused the random words being bold. This wasn't being used effectively so i've removed it. I haven't been able to replicate this so this could be a combination of things.

Comment: I am having the same problem with Lato in Chrome. But I don't have font-feature-settings defined anywhere. The only fix for me was to use a font other than Lato...

Comment: I just ran into this with Lato. What a strange issue!